# How to create a specific detailed page for all the posts in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have fetched all the posts using WP_Query, below is the code which I am using:

```
<?php 
 $args = array (
            'category__in' => 2,
            'order'   => 'DESC',
            );
 $i = 1;
 $work = new WP_Query( $args );
 if ( $work->have_posts() ) :
 while ( $work->have_posts() ) :
 $work->the_post();
 ?>
 <div class="timeline__content">
 <img src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" class="img-fluid" />
 <h2><?php echo the_title(); ?></h2>
 <p><?php $content = get_the_content(); echo mb_strimwidth($content, 0, 150, '...');?></p>
 <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>" class="detail-btn">Details</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

My issue is that the_permalink is not able to view that particular post.

I have also created a page for the post as shown below and used the WP_Query loop but the post it fetches is the last one.

```
<?php
 /*
 * Template Name: Post
 * Template Post Type: post, page, product
 */  
 ?>
```

How will I able to create a page properly for post.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already created single.php then this is most likely a permalink issue. Try setting the permalink to postname and saving.

If you haven't created single.php and your index.php is not calling the standard loop but a custom layout then you will get this issue. To resolve this you need to create single.php and I recommend that you take a look at template hierarchy here https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/